# Firebase Authentication with Angular: How to keep user session active when tabs are closed? onIdTokenChanged vs onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a personal project using Angular and firebase. We use firebase for authentication, After user logIn, we use accessTokens to pass to the backend. But accessTokens are valid only for an hour. We are trying ways to keep the session active w/o having the user to log-in again. Below is the code flow -

We call `GetTokens()` every time the app is refreshed (user tab close and open). Below is the implementation of GetTokens

`import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';`

```
GetTokens() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            user.getIdToken(true).then(idToken => {
            let oldJwtToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'));
            oldJwtToken['stsTokenManager']['accessToken'] = idToken
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', JSON.stringify(oldJwtToken))

            resolve(idToken);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

But  `user.getIdToken(true)` never gets executed. We even tried with `onIdTokenChanged`.
How do we solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Auth SDK automatically refreshes the user's token every hour as needed.  There's nothing you need to do to make that happen.  What you're doing wrong here is trying to wrap your auth state observer into a promise.  Since a promise only resolves once with the value provided by `resolve()`, it will never reflect any updates that the observer might produce.

You will need to use an observer to capture new tokens as they become available over time.  And you should use [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) to listen for new tokens, since they have a lifecycle that's different than the user's auth state.  Whether you make other software components check some global memory for the latest token, or push the token into other components is up to you.  But a promise is not the best way to manage things that changes over time.

Comment: Thanks. Let me make sure I understand, 1. I will remove wrapping auth state into a promise. 2. I will change onAuthStateChanged to onIdTokenChanged. Now, using this method do we get notified when tokens are expired? Is the logic right of listening to onIdTokenChanged and calling getIDTokens. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Yes, this is what you're supposed to do.

Comment: It did not work as expected. During app load, we subscribe to token changes using ```this.afAuth.onIdTokenChanges``` And ```getIdToken``` is wrapped inside the observer. But when do you think getIdToken will be called? After token has expired and during app load we are not seeing calls to getIdToken. Thoughts? Is there a good example to refer ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and share your code there.